# ¿Cómo crear una tabla mysql en la que una columna tiene atributo multiple_key?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Para hacer pruebas tengo que crear una tabla como otra existente que tiene los siguientes atributos:

```
int id 11 not_null primary_key auto_increment 
int id_aligxo 11 multiple_key 
int banc 4 unsigned zerofill 
int oficina 4 unsigned zerofill 
int dc 2 unsigned zerofill 
int compte 10 unsigned zerofill
```

He hecho esto:

```
CREATE TABLE comptes_prv 
(id INT(11) not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
id_aligxo INT(11),
banc INT(4) unsigned zerofill,
oficina INT(4) unsigned zerofill,
dc INT(2) unsigned zerofill,
compte INT(10) unsigned zerofill,
multiple key (id_aligxo),
PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

y me da error de sintaxis: `... near 'key (id_aligxo), PRIMARY KEY (id))' at line 8`

No sé como se asignar `multiple key` a la columna 2.

Comment: Te refieres a esto: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html ¿?

Comment: No creo. Yo solo tengo que crear una tabla que sea igual a la que contiene esa columna con el atributo "multiple key" para hacer pruebas y no sé como hay que poner ese atributo en el "create table".

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "multiple key"? Estoy mirando la documentación de MySQL y no encuentro "multiple key", lo más parecido es la caché de múltiple clave ([multiple key cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-key-caches.html)), pero no sé si es eso lo que quieres. Aparte ["multiple" no es una palabra reservada o keyword in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), que es por lo que te da el error.

Comment: Gracias por vuestras respuestas. Yo no se que es "multiple key". Tal como pongo en la consulta, ha salido al listar los atributos de una tabla que tengo que copiar para hacer pruebas. Esta tabla igual tiene unos 10 años. Si no se encuentra la voy a crear sin este atributo y a ver qué sucede. Repito: 1000 gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren dos posibilidades, no sé cual se adaptará mejor a tu caso...

Puedes hacer una Primary Key compuesta. Esto te obliga a usar los dos campos como clave primaria.

```
PRIMARY KEY (id, id_aligxo)
```

O haces una Primary Key y una Unique Key (clave alternativa). Esto te permite identificar el registro por cualquiera de los dos campos

```
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY (id_aligxo)
```